# Game theory book by Tirole,Fudenberg, zero up to first order of $\epsilon$,equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, epsilon-delta, nash-equilibrium

In [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads146/ebook/635671/MIT%20Press%20-%20Game%20Theory--Fudenberg%20&%20Tirole--579p.pdf) book on Game Theory, on page 186,I do not understand the very end of the page:

[T]he incentive to deviate$-$the left hand side of equation 5.18$-$ is $0$ in first order of $\epsilon$, so that preventing deviations require only a probability of punishment that is $0$ to first order as well.

Can someone clarify to me what is meant technically by these two sentences separately, and also why it is the case that they hold?

Comment: If no one answers, maybe check the original paper by Porter?

Comment: Good hint, thank you.(Optimal cartel trigger-price strategies. Journal of Economic Theory 29)